# Quantum central force problem and variable separations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

When dealing with a Hamiltonian of the type:

$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(r)$$

I have a big problem in understanding why we factor the total eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian into a radial and an angular term.

I think I understand that since $H, L^2$ and $L_z$ are three operators which, in this context, commute, it is convenient to look for the simultaneous eigenfunctions of the three operators. Therefore, when we write the TISE

$$H\psi_n(r,\theta,\phi)=E\psi_n(r,\theta,\phi)$$

the $\psi_n(r,\theta,\phi)$ refers to the simultaneous eigenfunctions of the three operators.

**The main problem is why we write**

$\psi_n(r,\theta,\phi)=f(R)F(\theta,\phi)$.

Is this related to the fact that the Hamiltonian can be separated into a radial term $H_r$ and an angular term $H_{\theta}$ and so we apply the standard resolution for a differential equation of this type, namely: we introduce a "test" function which consists of the product of single function each of one depends only on one variable: $T(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ and then we divide the whole differential equations by $T(x,y)$ and we obtain two differents ordinary differential equation?

For example in this discussion [Quantum Central Force Problem and Angular Momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/623077/quantum-central-force-problem-and-angular-momentum) in the first answer in the "Factorization of eigenvalues" paragraph, I read

> its obvious, this equation does not depend anymore on θ or ϕ and therefore the solution must simplify as:
> $\psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)=u_{nl}(r)Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$

**I ask you: why the solution must simplify in that way? Is that answer related to mine?**

If possible I would like an explanation that uses only time-independent Schrodinger equations and is not too difficult because I am on my first quantum mechanics course and am not very knowledgeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way of solving a partial differential equation is by separation of variables.  With a bit of experience it’s clear that, for potentials of the type $V(r)$, the angular part will not depend on $V$, and only the radial part will depend on $V$.

Separation of variables then allows you to transform the PDE into a set of ODEs linked by the separation constants.

It is not the *only* way to proceed but its advantages are numerous since you get out of that a complete set of functions, so that *any* solution can be written as a sum of products of separated functions.  Also it simplifies the search for solution since you only need to “solve again” the radial part : the radial ODE is different for every potential but the angular part remains the same for all $V(r)$ so you only need to do that angular part once.

Comment: Thank you, there is still something I don't understand though. Why with the separation of variables method we "get out of that a complete set of functions"? are you talking about the complete set of simultaneous eigenfunctions of the operators or in general, separating the variables, lead us to a "set of solution functions" which are complete by definition?

Comment: All the resulting ODE’s are Sturm-Liouville problems…

Comment: So why in a central field problem we say that $H,L^2,L_z$ commute with each other? Shouldn't we just show that the Hamiltonian is the sum of two parts that commute with each other and then we can factor the eigenfunction? Only $r$ and $L^2$ appear in the Hamiltonian, I should not be interested in $L_z$.

Comment: You can approach this from several angles and you’re right that in a central field there are degeneracies.   You need $L_z$ to identify the states with the same eigenvalue of $L^2$.  And $H$,$L^2$ and $L_z$ do commute.

Comment: ok so we use $L_z$ for "label" the eigenstates. What about my last question? Can you help me with that? I don't understand the motivation behind that sentence, if I want to separate variables I just need to write the total Hamiltonian as the sum of commutating parts, as far as I've understood.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by simplification.  By construction separation of variables leads to $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=R(r)\Theta(\theta,\phi)$ where $R(r)$ is a solution to an equation that depends only on $r$, and $\Theta(\theta,\phi)$ depends only on the angles.  So in this sense the method precisely looks for solutions that simplify in this way.  The lucky part is that *all* solutions are combos of functions of this type.